# Check ufw status and send Prometheus alert if not active

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager, ufw

I would need to check if ufw status is active, otherwise send an alert to a Slack channel.

I found out that the only way to check programmaticaly if ufw is active, is to check the exit code of `sudo ufw status | grep -w active` (see here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/533269/how-to-check-if-ufw-is-running-programmatically)

Having a Prometheus/Alert Manager system, I would like to create an alert in case the ufw status is inactive.
Would it be possible to achieve that using a PromQL query?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [textfile collecter in the node_exporter](https://github.com/prometheus/node_exporter#textfile-collector) to read a .prom file that you update via a systemd timer/service that runs the `ufw | grep` command

The service that updates the [Textfile](https://prometheus.io/docs/instrumenting/exposition_formats/#text-format-example) should create the file like:

```
# HELP ufw_is_up A flag to indicate if ufw is active. 
# TYPE ufw_is_up gauge
ufw_is_up 1
```

set your systemd timer to run more frequently than you have Prometheus set to scrape it and you will get a metric for whatever command you want!

I don't know anything about `ufw`, but you might be able to avoid having the complexity of the textfile or running the ufw command and just use the systemd/service manager of choice [collector](https://github.com/prometheus/node_exporter#disabled-by-default) for the node exporter.